# How to register a class with a dependency injected constructor? (SimpleIoC)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mvvm-light, ioc-container, viewmodellocator

I'm using MVVM Light in my project, but I'm not sure how to register a Viewmodel class in the ViewModelLocator class that takes a parameter in it's constructor.

I've looked through the [docs on IoC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx) but don't see anything relating to registering a class with a dependency injected constructor, ie that takes a parameter.

In the class I want to register, the constructor takes a list in it's parameter like this:

```
public ViewSubjectGradeViewModel(IEnumerable<ScoreModel> addedSubjectGradePairs)
```

But when I perform naviagation to the ViewModel class, I get an ActivationException, that details:

*"Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Cannot register: Multiple constructors found in ViewSubjectGradeViewModel but none marked with PreferredConstructor.
  Source=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras
  StackTrace:
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.GetPreferredConstructorInfo(IEnumerable`1 constructorInfos, Type resolveTo)
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.GetConstructorInfo(Type serviceType)
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.Register[TClass](Boolean createInstanceImmediately)
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc.SimpleIoc.RegisterTClass
       at LC_Points.ViewModel.ViewModelLocator..ctor()
       at LC_Points.LC_Points_WindowsPhone_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_ViewModelLocator()
       at LC_Points.LC_Points_WindowsPhone_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
  InnerException: 
"*

Does anyone know how to resolve this error and specify the "PreferredConstructor?"

The error itself is thrown at the line where I register the ViewModel class:

[image]

This is my ViewModelLocator class where the registration of VM's is defined:

```
namespace LC_Points.ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains static references to all the view models in the
    /// application and provides an entry point for the bindings.
    /// </summary>
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
        /// </summary>
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);


            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ScoreModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ViewSubjectGradeViewModel>();


        }

        public MainViewModel MainPage
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }


        public ViewSubjectGradeViewModel ViewSubjectGradePage
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ViewSubjectGradeViewModel>();
            }
        }


        public ScoreModel ScoreProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ScoreModel>();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't registered interface alone like this. 
You have register an interface with implementation of it:

```
class YourImplement: IEnumerable
{
 ....
}

SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IEnumerable, YourImplement>();
```

Or this:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IEnumerable>(()=>new YourImplement());
```

Comment: I just edited my above question for clarity, don't fully understand your solution. Can you take a look at it? Basically I'm trying to register a class that has a dependency in it's constructor of type IEnumerable list.

Answer (score 2):

Brian, is this what you're looking for...

Assuming:

```
interface IMyInterface {...}
class MyClass : IMyInterface {...}
IEnumerable myEnumerable = new List<string>();
```

Then:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMyInterface>( () => new MyClass(myEnumerable) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but i think what you are looking for is to decorate your constructor with the [PreferredConstructor()] attribute.

I suspect that your class "ViewSubjectGradeViewModel" must have multiple constructor. Probably a parameterless constructor, and the one you want to inject your dependency into as such :

```
public class ViewSubjectGradeViewModel
{
   public ViewSubjectGradeViewModel()
   {
       //default ctor
   }

   [PreferredConstructor()] //add this attribute
   public ViewSubjectGradeViewModel(IEnumerable<ScoreModel> addedSubjectGradePairs)
   {
       //dependency injected ctor
   }
}
```

The PreferredConstructorAttribute will tell which constructor SimpleIoc will call.